# How to import a reusable component from theme folder in react native?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

I want to import a reusable Button component from theme folder.

This is the path of the Button component:

```
\app\theme\components\Button.ts
```

And this is the code of `Button.ts`

```
import { typography } from "theme/typography";
import { ButtonProps } from "react-native-elements";

export const Button = {
titleStyle: {
    fontSize: typography.size,
    fontFamily: typography.primaryMedium,
    lineHeight: typography.size,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    marginHorizontal: typography.size
},
containerStyle: {
    borderRadius: typography.size * 2 + typography.size * 2
},
buttonStyle: {
    borderRadius: typography.size * 2 + typography.size
}
} as ButtonProps
```

And this is the component in which I want to import: `organizationdetails-screen.tsx`.

It's path is `\app\screens\superadmin-screens\organizationdetails-screen.tsx`.

I am trying to import the Button like this

```
import { Button } from '../../theme/components/Button';
```

But I am getting this error

[image]

I am using the Button like this:

```
<Button
     title="Add User"
     onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddNewUser')}
/>
```

When I hover over the button in Visual Studio Code it shows this error:

[image]

How do I import this reusable Button?

Comment: import button as import Button from '../../theme/components/Button'; remove {}

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working. It showed this error https://i.ibb.co/ZN77T4S/error3.jpg

Comment: Your `Button` is not a component. The `export const Button = {
titleStyle: {
    fontSize: typography.size,`  bit looks like a styles object: You need to return a react element from your `Button`, eg `export const Button = () => <Text>I'm not a button</Text>` - of course use the props, styles, and elements you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've defined just the button props in your `\app\theme\components\Button.ts` and are trying to use them as a component. This will not work.

Try this in your '\app\theme\components\Button.tsx':

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button as RNButton, ButtonProps } from 'react-native-elements`;
import { typography } from "theme/typography";


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: typography.size,
    fontFamily: typography.primaryMedium,
    lineHeight: typography.size,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    marginHorizontal: typography.size
  },
  containerStyle: {
    borderRadius: typography.size * 2 + typography.size * 2
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    borderRadius: typography.size * 2 + typography.size
  }
});


export const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => (
 <RNButton
  titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
  containerStyle={styles.containerStyle},
  buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
  {...props}
);
```

Comment: When I hover I get this error https://i.ibb.co/7VXdG7R/error4.png

Comment: Hm. Try changing Button.ts to Button.tsx